# How can I send audio? - aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

An error occurs when sending audio: `aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidHTTPUrlContent: Failed to get http url content`. Here is the code I use:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types = ["voice"])
async def getVoice(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id, "upload_voice")
    await bot.send_audio(message.from_user.id, "audio.mp3", performer = "Performer", title = "Title")
```

Comment: How did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send local file:

```
await bot.send_audio(message.from_user.id, open("audio.mp3", "r"), performer = "Performer", title = "Title")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also send that audio in a binary type:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler()
def send_audio(message: types.Message):
    with open("audio/file/path/audio.mp3", mode="rb") as file:
        binary_content = file.read()
    await message.reply(binary_content)
```